# How do I check when an input is changed?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried using the "input" event on the text box but it doesn't work. I've read a few posts on Stack Overflow but none of them worked.

Here's my most recent HTML and Javascript code using `onchange`:

```js
function updateResults(){
  document.write("Wroks");
}
```

```html
<input id="search-box" onchange="updateResults();"> </input>
```

I tried changing HTML to `onchange="updateResults;"` but didn't work.

I also tried changing HTML to `onchange="updateResults(event);"` and then Javascript to `function updateResults(event){...}`

Nothing that I tried worked.

Comment: Can you provide us a bit more of what you have tried?

Comment: Do you get errors on the console? Is updateResults defined so that it is global? Also with onchange the event will not fire until the input element lose focus

Comment: FYI: `onchange()` only fires when you lose focus from the textbox, re-test the scenario, try `alert()` instead of `document.write`

Comment: I'll check if it works when I unfocus .Is there any way over it updating when it updates?

Comment: You could also add a on keyup listener.

Comment: What is your actual desired result? Do you want to know when the input's value is no longer the default? When? As soon as it's changed, or when the user has moved ou the focus out of, or away from, the input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks fine to me. If you make any changes then you'll see the function get called as soon as you lose focus (`onchange` only happens when you blur). If you want more immediate results you can use `oninput` instead, like so:

```js
function updateResults(){
    document.write("Wroks");
}
```

```html
<input id="search-box" oninput="updateResults();" />
```

Another way is to use event listeners, if you want to keep javascript out of the markup:

```js
function updateResults() {
  document.write("Wroks");
}

document.getElementById("search-box").addEventListener("input", updateResults);
```

```html
<input id="search-box" />
```

The above however will only work if the DOM has already been loaded when the javascript is run. You could put it in an onload event, or include the javascript after the DOM markup.

Alternatively you could attach the event listener to the document and check for the ID whenever the event is triggered. There are pros and cons to this method. Since the function doesn't attach to the element directly, the DOM will not need to be loaded yet. If the element is removed and a new one with the same ID is added, it will still work. Also, if you add your content dynamically after the page loads, you will not need to worry about attaching the listener later. However, this function will be called every time any input on the page is registered, which theoretically could slow the page down (e.g. if you have a lot of these types of listeners), although probably minimally.

```js
function updateResults() {
  document.write("Wroks");
}

document.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  if (e.target.id === "search-box") {
    updateResults();
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="search-box" />
```

Comment: Now it's the event listeners that weren't working for me originally. I got a comment saying use oninput instead of onchange which fixed it :) Thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 3):

document.write("Wroks"); will replace everything in your window with "Wroks".

try this:

```
<input id="search-box" onchange="updateResults();"> </input>
<script>
function updateResults(){
    console.log('Works');
}
</script>
```

You also may want to consider using jQuery because then you could do a lot more out of the box with this.  for example:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="search-box">

<script>
$('#search-box').on('change',function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
})
</script>
```

The above code will give you the value of the input on change.

Comment: Thanks! I never knew document.write did it on everything.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
<input id="search-box" onchange="javascript:updateResults();"> </input>
```

or:

```
<input id="search-box" onchange="javascript:document.updateResults();"> </input>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear whether you want the JavaScript to fire when the user finishes updating the textbox, or after every character is input.

*This will fire after the user "commits" to their input, often by clicking something else.*

HTML

```
<input id="search-box" />
```

JavaScript

```
function updateResults(){
    alert("Works");
}

document.getElementById("search-box").addEventListener("change", updateResults, false);
```

*This will fire after every key is pressed (and so forth).*

HTML

```
<input id="search-box" />
```

JavaScript

```
function updateResults(){
    alert("Works");
}

document.getElementById("search-box").addEventListener("input", updateResults, false);
```

Comment: An `<input>` is a void element, it has no children and therefore no closing tag; it's written as above or as `<input />`, but not as `<input></input>`.

Comment: Yeah. Good point. Thanks. I didn't really think about that when I copy/pasted from the question.

Comment: You may want to correct your HTML, under those circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the question, you want to know when a user types in one letter/number and then call your function.

This would be "onkeyup":

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()">
```

You could also use onkeydown. See also http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

When you use onchange, this works too, but only after the input is finished. Either when the user presses enter or after leaving the textbox.

If all of this doesn't work, turn on Javascript in your Browser.